# SharedPreference giving me unknown LOG

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, logcat

I want to know what the log that shows means when the Buttom Navigation Bar is clicked, The text information inside this item is stored in the prefrence.

this is the code for navigation item when clicked :

```
case R.id.navigation_gift:
    View view = View.inflate(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.section_fragment_69, null);
    TextView txtEmtiaz = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtEmtiaz);
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("entire", 0);
    txtEmtiaz.setText(sp.getString("tik", ""));
    Log.e("POPI", "txt in main2 :" + String.valueOf(txtEmtiaz));
```

This is the Log information that is displayed:

```
/POPI: txt in main2 :android.widget.TextView{1e42d479 V.ED.... ......ID 0,0-0,0 #7f09016d app:id/txtEmtiaz}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to get text from `txtEmtiaz` and then set it to `sp` shared preference.

**Problem is at below line:**

```
txtEmtiaz.setText();
```

Change to:

```
sp.putString("tik", txtEmtiaz.getText());
```

**Problem in log:**

```
  Log.e("POPI", "txt in main2 :" + String.valueOf(txtEmtiaz));
```

You are trying to print `txtEmtiaz` i.e. `txtEmtiaz` object which of course you can not.

You should use like below to print value (text) of `txtEmtiaz` TextView:

```
  Log.e("POPI", "txt in main2 :" + txtEmtiaz.getText());
```

Comment: `You are trying to print value of txtEmtiaz which of course you can not.`. Kinda wrong, kinda right. You can print the 'values', in other words the representations of the particular TextView just fine.

Comment: @ZUNJAE missed some explanation. Please check, added now. I wanted to say that you can not print `txtEmtiaz` object as it is but you need to get value i.e. text of it via `txtEmtiaz.getText()` which i added. Hope it is clear now.

Comment: I did what you said. And in the LOG I get the correct number. But I want to know what the previous LOG is about numbers and words.
What is the meaning of 1e42d479 or 0,0-0,0 @VicJordan

Comment: @VicJordan Yes, with your answer I was able to correct the LOG and get the right answer. But look at the end, I wanted to know what the meaning of numbers and words meant.

Comment: @AliGhaemi that numbers are hash value of object reference.

Comment: I know how to accept the answer. I just want to know about this and how these numbers are created. Even if you know the smallest guide, please tell me.
To at least get the highest percentage of my answer

Comment: And very much thanks for your timely assistance. I got my answer.

Comment: @AliGhaemi Never mind. Please don't forget to give upvote to my answer.

Answer (score 4):

**Try this**

**You are using SharedPreference with no name.**

Try this SharedPreference with name:

**Setting values in Preference**

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 editor.putString("name", "HD");

 editor.apply();
```

**Retrieve data from preference:**

```
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
    String restoredText = prefs.getString("text", null);
    if (restoredText != null) {
      String name = prefs.getString("name", "HD");
     txtEmtiaz.setText(name);

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to print a TextView. You want to print the content of the TextView instead, use:

`txtEmtiaz.getText().toString()`

Comment: i know. i want to know what each word and number mean in log

Comment: look at the toString() method in the TextView class if you want to know what each value means.